# nginx caching few upstreams on same server

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to test to build a nginx server to cache few servers.
My nginx conf is like that :

```
...
http {

    upstream srv1 {
      ip_hash;
      server srv1.domain1.fr:443;
    }

    upstream srv2 {
      ip_hash;
      server srv2.domain2.fr:443;
    }
...
proxy_cache_path /nginx/cache/cache_temp use_temp_path=off keys_zone=cache_temp:10m max_size=10g inactive=10m;
    proxy_cache cache_temp;
...
#srv1
server {
 listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name srv1.domain1.fr;

all ssl settings...
location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|wmv|avi|mpg|mpeg|mp4|htm|html|js|css|mp3|swf|ico|flv|woff|woff2|ttf|svg)$ {
                proxy_cache_valid 12h;
                proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
                add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
                proxy_pass https://srv1;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_cache_valid 12h;
                proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
                add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
                proxy_pass https://srv1;
        }
}

#srv2
server {
 listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name srv2.domain2.fr;

all ssl settings...
location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|wmv|avi|mpg|mpeg|mp4|htm|html|js|css|mp3|swf|ico|flv|woff|woff2|ttf|svg)$ {
                proxy_cache_valid 12h;
                proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
                add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
                proxy_pass https://srv2;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_cache_valid 12h;
                proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
                add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
                proxy_pass https://srv2;
        }
}
```

so in my dns, I put the same IP for srv1.domain1.fr and srv2.domain2.fr
that works well but when I switch between both, issue occured : cache is the same
so I try to find a way to get separated cache

any idea ?
thanks

add more conf :

```
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_read_timeout 10s;
    proxy_send_timeout 10s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 10s;
    proxy_cache_path /nginx/cache/cache_temp use_temp_path=off keys_zone=cache_temp:10m max_size=10g inactive=10m;
    proxy_cache cache_temp;
    proxy_cache_methods GET HEAD;
    proxy_cache_key $uri;
    proxy_cache_valid 404 3s;
    proxy_cache_lock on;
    proxy_cache_lock_age 5s;
    proxy_cache_lock_timeout 1h;
    proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
    proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
    proxy_cache_use_stale updating;
```

Comment: if you don't made a mistake in other part of the code it must work, maybe you need to check proxy_cache_key http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_key , but again it seems right.

Comment: what's the synthom? Can you post the logs?

Comment: error.log is empty, maybe I need to increase level
issue is just that when I enter fqdn from one of them, it works, then if I enter the second, it replies with the first one

Comment: with warn level, nothing better
to explain in more details :
I go first to : https://srv1.domain1.fr => no issue
now I go to : https://srv2.domain2.fr => I get the srv1
it seems the first in cache wins, if I add in srv2 "/something", it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change proxy_cache_key

From

proxy_cache_key $uri;

To

proxy_cache_key $scheme$proxy_host$request_uri;

Definitely it will solve this behavior.